# Appveyor use of "libs" git "sub-module" for separately compiled Windows plugins (open-source)

Tags: open-source, git-submodules, appveyor

We are having trouble compiling Windows plugins for an opensource application using Appveyor because Appveyor apparently does not support a sub-module for "libs" used by all the plugins.

We would like to be able to build for an earlier Windows version of plugins which uses wxWidgets 3.1.2, however we are not putting wxWidgets 3.1.2 in the sub-module.

Use of a git sub-module fails when using Appveyor. We were hoping it would work. Any suggestions or advice is welcomed.  Should we try using git to build these Windows plugins instead of Appveyor?

Comment: Is this link a part of the answer? https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/    The trouble is we are Open Source and cannot do private.